# How to update table in database while file is being transferred using django celery?

Tags: django, django-celery

I have a task like this in Django:

```
from celery import task
import subprocess, celery

@celery.task
def file(password, source12, destination):
    return subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', source12, destination], 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

This transfers file from one server to another using `rsync`. 
Here's my views:

```
def sync(request):
    """Sync the files into the server with the progress bar"""
    choices = request.POST.getlist('choice') 
    for i in choices:
        new_source = source +"/"+ i 
        start_date1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        source12 = new_source.replace(' ', '') #Remove whitespaces
        result = file.delay(password, source12, destination)
        result.get()
        a = result.ready()
        start_date = start_date1.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %H:%M%p")

        extension = os.path.splitext(i)[1][1:] #Get the file_extension
        fullname = os.path.join(destination, i) #Get the file_full_size to calculate size
        st = int(os.path.getsize(fullname))
        f_size = size(st, system=alternative)
```

I want to update the table in database which I want to update and show it to the user. The table should be updated while the file is being transferred. How can I do that using `django-celery`?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing too special about Celery when it comes to Django. You can just update the database like you would normally do. The only thing you may need to think about are the transactions.

Just to be sure I would recommend using either manual commits or autocommits to update the database. Although I would suggest using redis/memcached instead of the database for these kind of status updates. They are more suited for this purpose.